# Pass Return URL in Callback MFA using Microsoft B2c

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, identity

I have Authentication using Microsoft B2C already in place, Where we are passing URL (CallbackMFA) after successful login. Now I would like to pass Return URL so that my application desired web page will be loaded after successful login rather always loading Home page.

CallbackMFA has already ReturnURL logic written (if we have query string as ReturnURL, it will redirect else redirects to home) but whenever we send returnURL it is not recognized. Which is best place to pass returnURL

Answer (score 1):

You can surely pass your `redirect url` as the call back url in your ***Azure ADB2C Application*** as shown below. Ensure that the `redirect url` configured as below in your application corresponds to the page that you want your application should be redirected to. Thus when you configure in this way the application should load the said page after successful ***authentication to Azure AD B2C.***

```
https://tenantname.b2clogin.com/tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
```

[image]

For more information please refer this ***Microsoft Documentation***:[***Configure session behavior in Azure Active Directory B2C***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow)